# Sending multiple parameters to Actions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to send multiple parameters to an action in ASP.NET MVC. I'd also like the URL to look like this:

```
http://example.com/products/item/2
```

instead of:

```
http://example.com/products/item.aspx?id=2
```

I'd like to do the same for sender as well, here's the current URL:

```
http://example.com/products/item.aspx?id=2&sender=1
```

How do I accomplish both with C# in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're ok with passing things in the query string, it's quite easy. Simply change the Action method to take an additional parameter with a matching name:

```
// Products/Item.aspx?id=2 or Products/Item/2
public ActionResult Item(int id) { }
```

Would become:

```
// Products/Item.aspx?id=2&sender=1 or Products/Item/2?sender=1
public ActionResult Item(int id, int sender) { }
```

ASP.NET MVC will do the work of wiring everything up for you.

If you want a clean looking URL, you simply need to add the new route to Global.asax.cs:

```
// will allow for Products/Item/2/1
routes.MapRoute(
        "ItemDetailsWithSender",
        "Products/Item/{id}/{sender}",
        new { controller = "Products", action = "Item" }
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the appropriate definitions for the route in your global.asax.

Comment: @Reza - I've added the URLs as comments in the code. If you want a cleaner URL, you need to add a custom route to global.asax.cs.

Answer (score 13):

If you want a pretty URL, then add the following to your `global.asax.cs`.

```
routes.MapRoute("ProductIDs",
    "Products/item/{id}",
    new { controller = Products, action = showItem, id="" }
    new { id = @"\d+" }
 );

routes.MapRoute("ProductIDWithSender",
   "Products/item/{sender}/{id}/",
    new { controller = Products, action = showItem, id="" sender="" } 
    new { id = @"\d+", sender=@"[0-9]" } //constraint
);
```

And then to use the needed actions:

```
public ActionResult showItem(int id)
{
    //view stuff here.
}

public ActionResult showItem(int id, int sender)
{
    //view stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use any route rule for example:

```
{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}
```

also you can use get params like `:baseUrl?param1=1&param2=2`

and check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488061/passing-multiple-parameters-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-also-generating-on-the), i hope it will help you.