# Generate URL with multiple input parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to generate an URL from my MVC application Razor view which will contain multiple parameter inputs like this: `example.com/Index?id=1&bool=true`

I already tried this: `@Url.Action("Index?id=1&bool=true", "MyController")` which however does not work at all.

I would like to ask if there are any ideas how I can get an output like in the example above? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586336/sending-multiple-parameters-to-actions-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: `@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName", new { id = 1, xxx  = true })` (where `xxx` is your `boolean` property - it cannot be named `bool`)

Comment: /controllername/index/1?xxx=True i am getting output like that. but i want like this-> Index?id=1&bool=true

Comment: If you mean you want the controller name to be omitted, then you cannot unless you write custom route definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change your default Route `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

with

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

And then use your `URL.Action`:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName", new { id = 1, @bool = true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the input in hidden fields so when you will navigate to other page, the data will automatically be sent via query string. e.g

`@Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id);`

the Id will be sent in the query string

Comment: OP wants to generate a url, **not** submit a form!

Comment: Thanks for identifying, what I need to tell him was, that he should save the items in the hidden fields which he wants in the query string.

Comment: No where in the question is OP generating a form (this has nothing to do with the question)