# Getting a string from URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

With the following code in controller, I can pass the value of genre as "rock" with this url: "http://localhost:2414/Store/Browse?genre=rock"

```
public string Browse(string genre)
    {
        string message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Store.Browse, Genre = "
    + genre);

        return message;
    }
```

I want to pass the same value of genre when the URL is "http://localhost:2414/Store/Browse/rock"

How can I do that?

Comment: There is related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488061/passing-multiple-parameters-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-also-generating-on-the)
and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155864/asp-net-mvc-problem-passing-parameters-to-the-controller).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your controller action shouldn't look as it currently does. All controller actions should return an [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx) and you shouldn't be HTML encoding parameters inside. That's the responsibility of the view:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
{
    string message = string.Format("Store.Browse, Genre = {0}", genre);
    // the cast to object is necessary to use the proper overload of the method
    // using view model instead of a view location which is a string        
    return View((object)message); 
}
```

and then in your view display and HTML encode like this:

```
<%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
```

Now back to your question about handling urls like this. You could simply define the following route in your `Global.asax`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{genre}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", genre = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and then `http://localhost:2414/Store/Browse/rock` will invoke the `Browse` action on the `Store` controller passing `rock` as `genre` parameter.

Comment: 'id' should be 'genre' in the route default values.

Answer (score 0):

I want to correct one of the answers made above for the benefit of others;

*"First of all your controller action shouldn't look as it currently does. All controller actions should return an ActionResult..."*

Controller actions should return the most specific type based on what you are returning. E.g. If you are returning a Partial View, then use PartialViewResult, or if you are returning Json, then return a JsonResult. It is always best practice to return the most specific type, that way unit testing will be more accurate.

P.S Controller Actions can also return, Strings, Booleans etc..